# Multi-Part Identifier in SQL Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert values from an exisiting table into a temp table. However, I just want the values from one table which equal the value of another table to be inserted into my temp table (sorry if that was confusing)

Here is my code:

```
select * into
#gl_chart_av
from glchart where glchart.account_code = AdaptInvalidAccts.account_code
```

I'd like just the data from the glchart table inserted into my temp table who's account code in the glchart table matches that of the account codes found in the AdaptInvalidAccts table. But, I get a multi-part identifier error. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select glchart.* 
into #gl_chart_av
from 
    glchart 
    inner join AdaptInvalidAccts on glchart.account_code=AdaptInvalidAccts.account_code
```

or

```
select * 
into #gl_chart_av
from glchart 
where account_code in (
    select account_code from AdaptInvalidAccts
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a case where you would use an EXISTS. It will only return records from glchart that are present in AdaptInvalidAccts based on the account_code matching.

```
select * 
into #gl_chart_av
from glchart 
where EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM AdaptInvalidAccts
WHERE glchart.account_code = AdaptInvalidAccts.account_code)
```

As for the identifier error, nowhere in your code are you declaring the AdaptInvalidAccts alias on AdaptInvalidAccts.account_code